# How can I pass a value into a function without using function parameters?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype-programming

I have a factory function that returns a React Query mutation hook, like this:

```
function useMutationFactory(mutationFunction: (axios: Axios) => (params: any) => any) {
    const baseURL = getBaseURL(); // Retrieves the Base URL (this is dynamic)
    const axios = useAxios({baseURL}); // Creates an Axios instance with the URL
    ...
    return useMutation(mutationFunction(axios));
}
```

The usual mutation function for `useMutation` is `(params: any) => any`, I have to curry it to pass axios to the user. I want to see if it's possible to have axios inside of `mutationFunction` without currying.

The idea I have is to use prototypes, and write wrapper functions for every axios http method. Something like this:

```
const Mutation = {
    queryGet: (...params: Parameters<Axios["get"]>) => {
        const axios = this.prototype.axios; // Not sure about this part
        return axios.get(...params);
    }
}
```

The mutation function from users would be something like this:

```
const mutation = useMutationFactory((params) => {
     const res = Mutation.queryGet("/");
});
```

I'm stuck on getting axios to `Mutation`. Ideally, axios isn't passed to the user, so I have to set axios inside `useMutationFactory`. I can't use `apply()` or `call()`, since the user would have to call that (I'm assuming). I'm still very new at Object prototyping, so I would appreciate any suggestions or help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, have the function do something with a variable in the global scope, update / change the variable in the global scope to the value you want to pass to the function, then call the function so that it reads the updated value of the variable.

I'm on my phone atm else I would give a code example. Hope this helps though.

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't work. Other than the fact that global scoped variables aren't a good idea in the first place, a global scope variable would be overwritten as soon as another hook is created, destroying the instance for the first function.

Comment: I agree, global vars are like public toilet walls, best not touched! It was just food for thought. Functions don t just have açcess to vars defined in the global scope

Comment: Yeah, I figured there would be an answer with prototypal inheritance. The factory would set the axios instance for Mutation, then when the wrapper method is called, the correct instance would be available in the object.